# Raw Socket returning -1 with sendto function

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, network-programming

Im using a raw socket to forge packets and send them out. But the sendto function returns a -1. Does anyone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    int sock_r = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.217.19.14");
    saddr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    int len = sendto(sock_r,"Hello World\n",strlen("Hello World\n"),0,(struct sockaddr*)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
    printf("Length = %d\n",len);
    close(sock_r);
}
```

Comment: What is the `errno` value? (you can also use `perror`). Have the executing user enough rights to write on raw socket ?

Comment: Yes I am running the file with sudo and the socket file descriptor value is 3. The error I receive is Invalid Argument. Which I'm pretty sure is referring to the sockaddr I'm using. I don't know what type of sockaddr to send along with this type of raw socket

Comment: Did you assert that the value returned by `socket(...)` is valid?

Comment: yes the socket is working. i.e the value is not -1 and also it can recv packets. Also I checked that if I send a packet to the sockaddr from which i received a packet, it is working. The problem here lies with the type of sockaddr.